# Typescript parameter type depending on another parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I want to create generic function for setStore, the function is simple:

```
const setStore = <T>(store:T) => <K extends keyof T,U extends boolean>(property: K,data: U extends true? Partial<T[K]>:T[K],partialUpdate:U) => {
if (partialUpdate) {
      store[property] = { ...store[property], ...data }
    } else {
      store[property] = data // Error Type 'U extends true ? Partial<T[K]> : T[K]' is not assignable to type 'T[K]'.
    }
}
```

I want data's type to be T[K] or Partial<T[K]> depending on the `partialUpdate` parameter is true or false. But I get the error `Type 'U extends true ? Partial<T[K]> : T[K]' is not assignable to type 'T[K]'.` because somehow typescript can't decide whether the data type is `T[K]` or `Partial<T[K]>`

Answer (score 1):

Just tell typescript that data really is a T[K].

```js
const setStore = <T>(store:T) => <K extends keyof T,U extends boolean>(property: K,data: U extends true? Partial<T[K]>:T[K],partialUpdate:U) => {
  if (partialUpdate) {
        store[property] = { ...store[property], ...data }
  } else {
        store[property] = data as T[K]
  }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCmUDKUQCd4wLwwDwBUA+ACmnXgC58BKbQvAaRngA8p4wATCGAa3gCeIAGYx8AGgCqzNh24wARiBAAbeAEMwJAA5oQ2+GigCKMBuM7qo609NbsuPKGgCu8APwwACuqMBLdRUCAG0GAF1CKlCw8W1fKACVSW1LdgpJWix6AG8AKBgYP1FiOP9A5NT4WjyC2tqyDGDdfUNjMOwYbJgAOl6G+Ca9AyMBGJ7e1PUYAF98meYVBE65uoL+wZaR9pxJmHUefGi52dnc3IRkVAxiLvUFYFNb0wAmcUVTAGZ56epiACI7sA-m8nq93jAAKwzN7ONzUc6IFDkG57e6PPYvN4KT7fX4A+7AzoYsHYyHQmDCQIIeEXJHXW5ook2GAknHTGZ4wGE0Hk2FVBGXZEMh5MzHgr7sn7-Lkg4nkymLKpAA)

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks :)  it sounds like a solution. But I just try to avoid to use type assertion, because maybe it's not properly typed. And i don't know why Typescript can't figure out the proper type in this case